# Why is my C# method not being called from AJAX?

Tags: javascript, c#, sql, ajax, json

I am trying to call the following C# method:

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static string getJSONdata()
    {
        string jsonString = "";
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 10 * FROM DRAW ORDER BY DrawID DESC;", con))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    List<Dot> _Dot = new List<Dot>();

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        Dot dot = new Dot();
                        dot.x = (int.Parse(reader["xCoord"].ToString()));
                        dot.y = (int.Parse(reader["yCoord"].ToString()));

                        if (reader["DrawID"] != DBNull.Value)
                            dot.i = (int.Parse(reader["DrawID"].ToString()));

                        _Dot.Add(dot);
                    }
                    JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                    jsonString = jss.Serialize(_Dot);
                }
            }
        }
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(" JSON: " + jsonString);

        return jsonString;
    }
```

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
$.ajax({
                url: 'Default.aspx/getJSONdata',
                data: '{ }',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);
                }
            });
```

First, I am getting the ajax error. No idea why it's not called. 
Second, I am still not sure I am returning the correct JSON data I want, whether in the correct format or not. Thanks for your help.

Edit. It is returning a JSON string correctly.

Note: the `connectionString` works in another function, so that's not it.

Comment: What HTTP response do you have back?

Comment: @zerkms 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: So run your project with debugger and see what fails?

Comment: @zerkms When I remove the data (I don't need it) and contentType I get a 200 error.

Comment: Specifically SyntaxError Unexpected Token <

Comment: So where is it unexpected?

Comment: Please try removing only data and check. if still it doesn't work let me know what error you are getting

Comment: @kishoreVM Removing data gives me the same error.

Comment: in your Debug.WriteLine(" JSON: " + jsonString); is your json string coming fine ?  is this happening only with specific browser like chrome or any browser same issue ? Some times this will happen if the content you are sending is too huge. try sending top 10 rows .. and check

Comment: Yes, the JSON line comes through in the output and on the HTML page if I put it into a paragraph tag.Getting the same errors in Chrome and FF.

Answer (score 0):

Download and install [Fidder4](http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler/fiddler4).

This will allow you to see the traffic between your page and your server.  You can see the actual call URL and then paste it into a browser to see what it returns. This will give you a tool to solve this type of problem going forward.